# How does it changed this syntax in Symfony 3.0.4

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

This syntax work correctly in symfony2 but it changed in Symfony3.

How could I retrieve parameter `$em` in `FormType` with symfony3?

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form=$this->createForm(EtMenusType($em),$menu);
```

```
class EtMenusType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    */
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em=$em;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms#defining-your-forms-as-services

> **Your form type might have some external dependencies.** You can define your form type as a service, and inject all dependencies you need.
>
> You might want to use a service defined as app.my_service in your form type. Create a constructor to your form type to receive the service:
>
> ```
> // src/AppBundle/Form/Type/TaskType.php
> namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;
>
> use App\Utility\MyService;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
>
> class TaskType extends AbstractType
> {
>     private $myService;
>
>     public function __construct(MyService $myService)
>     {
>         $this->myService = $myService;
>     }
>
>     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
>     {
>         // You can now use myService.
>         $builder
>             ->add('task')
>             ->add('dueDate', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
>             ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
>         ;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Define your form type as a service.
>
> ```
> # src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
> services:
>     app.form.type.task:
>         class: AppBundle\Form\Type\TaskType
>         arguments: ["@app.my_service"]
>         tags:
>             - { name: form.type }
> ```